# "result is null" error when working around _blank deficiency in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Using a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865433/96588) to be able to check the contents of a new tab, I get unexpected results. If I play the test case, the following line fails:

```
storeEval | javascript{"selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().open('', 'my_window')"} | my_window
```

with the following error message:

```
[error] Threw an exception: result is null
```

The following alternative statements show the exact same symptoms:

```
getEval | window.open("", "my_window")
getEval | selenium.browserbot.openWindow("", "my_window")
```

Now, if I double-click it, it *doesn't* fail, but it opens up a new window, which I think the original solution didn't intend (the next step is to click on a link in the *parent* window, after all). At this point I can click on the parent window, manually run the next step to launch the link, manually change back to the child window (`selectWindow | my_window` says it can't find that window), and manually run each of the following steps to check the contents of the new window.

How do I proceed from here to make the test properly *automatic*?

Update: There is a built-in action for opening windows, but it also fails. Maybe this verbatim log output can shed some light on what's going on:

```
[info] Executing: |store | license_window | windowName |
...
[info] Executing: |openWindow | | ${windowName} |
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/recorder.js, lineNumber -> 74
```

The relevant lines from recorder.js:

```
66: window.open = function(url, windowName, windowFeatures, replaceFlag) {
...
74:            if (result.wrappedJSObject) {
75:                result = result.wrappedJSObject;
76:            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your browser doesn't allow pop-up for your web site. Go to options > Content > Exceptions for block pop-up windows and add your web site address.

Comment: `getEval | window.open("", "my_window")` and `getEval | selenium.browserbot.openWindow("", "my_window")` both fail with `[error] Threw an exception: result is null`.

Comment: It seems that your browser doesn't allow pop-up for your web site. Go to options > Content > Exceptions for block pop-up windows and add your web site address.

Comment: Awesome, that was the fix! Can you add it as an answer? There was no warning from the browser, which is odd.