# Testing facebook connect with selenium

Tags: facebook, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm having trouble switching between the popup windows in Selenium IDE.  I'm using Facebook's test user system to create a test user (this part works perfectly), then wrote some steps to remove the authorization for the app they belong to (kind of annoying that Facebook doesn't let you specify whether or not you'd like your test account to have already authorized the app).  Regardless, once I have a fresh test user signed into Facebook with no existing authorization for my app, I have it open the page containing the connect button, then:

1. `waitForCondition  selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('fbSignInAnchor')`
2. `click css=#fbSignInAnchor > img`

At this point, Facebook launches that popup window with the authorization. I've tried using `waitForPopup`, but it fails to detect the popup. So now I have it `pause 5000` then `selectWindow title=Log into [my app's name]`, but this fails when it's run in sequence -- if I manually execute this step, it works fine.

What's the best way to have it wait for the popup window, then select it so I can run the next steps, which are `clickAndWait name=grant_required_clicked` and `click name=grant_clicked` (clicking the two submit buttons to authorize the app).

Comment: Note that the Facebook test api does seem to allow users to be set up as authorized or not authorized by your app. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ Set Installed = false (it is true by default). Note there is also the permissions parameter to allow you to specify what permissions the app should be given, if you set installed to true.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamMc, not sure how I missed this.  This saves me several unnecessary steps I had written to remove the authorization!

Comment: Hope you come right @ehed - I gave up trying to GUI test my app due to time constraints- how sad- but I want to try again. In fact, that's how I knew the API had this option, so I'm glad my work was not in vain - it helped you! I always regret not having test automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197217/selenium-href-blank-new-window-test/4865433#4865433) and assign some ID to your pop up:

```
getEval | selenium.browserbot.findElement('css=#fbSignInAnchor>img').target='my_window'
getEval | window.open("", "my_window")
click | css=#fbSignInAnchor > img
selectWindow | my_window
waitForElementPresent | name=grant_required_clicked
clickAndWait | name=grant_required_clicked
```

Comment: Hm, it does not seem to work, I think because the <a> tag in this case invokes some javascript rather than opening a new page via href=.  If I command-click on the button (open in new tab), it still creates a popup.

Comment: @ehed - have you tried `waitForElementPresent | name=grant_required_clicked` after `click | css=#fbSignInAnchor > img` without any `waitForPopup` and `selectWindow`?